# opencv drawing rectangle from contours

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin

I am trying to detect moving objects by drawing rectangle around them using openCV in Android App with `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` object.

I have already extracted foreground mask and found contours but It seems like that `Imgproc.rectangle()` doesn't draw rectangles.

```
override fun onCameraFrame(inputFrame: CvCameraViewFrame?): Mat? {
        val minContourWidth = 35
        val minContourHeight = 35
        val threshold = 100.0
        val kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5.0, 5.0))

        frame = inputFrame?.rgba()
        backSub?.apply(frame, fgMask)
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(fgMask, fgMask, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) // fill holes
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(fgMask, fgMask, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) //remove noise
        Imgproc.dilate(fgMask, fgMask, kernel)

        val cannyOutput = Mat()
        Imgproc.Canny(fgMask, cannyOutput, threshold, threshold * 2)
        val contours = ArrayList<MatOfPoint>()
        val hierarchy = Mat()
        Imgproc.findContours(cannyOutput, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)
        hierarchy.release()
        Log.i(TAG, "contours size: " + contours.size)

        for(contour in contours) {

            val approxCurve = MatOfPoint2f()
            val contour2f = MatOfPoint2f()
            contour.convertTo(contour2f, CvType.CV_32FC2)
            val approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * 0.02
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true)
            val points = MatOfPoint()
            approxCurve.convertTo(points, CvType.CV_8UC4)
            val rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points)

            Imgproc.rectangle(frame, Point(rect.x.toDouble(), rect.y.toDouble()),
                Point((rect.x + rect.width).toDouble(), (rect.y + rect.height).toDouble()), Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0), 3)
        }

        return frame
    }
```

[Link to my repository](https://github.com/MCozhusheck/AndroidObjectTracking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/maciej/imageprocessing/MainActivity.kt)

Comment: Did you somehow modify the opencv classes to straighten or to make your preview in full screen? If you did, what did you change?

Comment: It is working for me, what values you get for your rectangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work, turns out i had to change `contour.convertTo(contour2f, CvType.CV_32FC2)` to `approxCurve.convertTo(points, CvType.CV_32SC2)` according to [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/207309/drawing-rectangles-from-contours-in-android/) on opencv Q&A forum.